# Ionic3 - Splash screen forever

Tags: cordova, ionic3, splash-screen

I built a simple app using Ionic (version3) and when I run it in the browser (using the command: ionic server --lab) it works fine, when I run in a device (Android 7) I run into a problem: I get a white screen forever... does anybody know what it might be? 
Thanks in advance

Here is my app.components.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@Component({  
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})

export class MyApp {  
  rootPage:any = HomePage;  

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {    
    platform.ready().then(() => {      
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.      
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.      
      statusBar.styleDefault();     
       splashScreen.hide();    
     }); 
  }
}
```

It is my config.xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>bibliotecaApp</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content original-src="index.html" src="***" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.1.11" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^5.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-datepicker" spec="^0.9.3" />
    <engine name="android" spec="^7.0.0" />
</widget>
```

Comment: any errors you got

Comment: @MohanGopi, I got no errors, I just saw a warn in the console, which says: tried calling statusbar.styledefault but cordova is not available

Comment: can you share your app.component.ts file code

Comment: Sure I can! I just edited my question and added that, Thanks @MohanGopi

Comment: inside your config.xml file `<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />` make like this

Comment: I edited the question adding the config.xml file, I tried out what you said but it still keeps on showing the splash screen forever ;(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162901/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-matheus-minguini).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the app with the debug command so it tells you what the problem is :

```
ionic run android -l -c -s --debug
```

make sure your phone is plugged in when you run this command

Comment: I ran using the command you said, and I got a warn saying: tried calling statusbar.styledefault but cordova is not available

Answer (score 0):

Connect your device to your PC via USB Cable and Enable USB debugging mode then run the adb logcat command in command line to see the errors

Command is

```
adb logcat "*:E"
```

It will log a lot of output on the command line wait till it throws the warnings and errors slowly than click on your app icon and launch it, you will see any issue related to your app on the screen. Click `ctrl+c` to stop it.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply, I did what you suggested, but there was no errors, just something weird, I saw in the logs this: validate_display: 255 error 3008 (BAD_DISPLAY), have you ever come across this?